# Dynamic memory allocator (heap)

Tags: c

My goal is to create my own "malloc" and "free" functions. I'm only doing this for practice so  I'm not interested in speed/performance. Instead I would go for a an easy approach so I can understand easier.

Where can I get started with this? Can you give me some pointers as to how to do it or tell me what I need to use to create these functions?

Comment: do you mean creating your own _true functions from scratch_ or writing wrapper functions around them?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422061/malloc-implementation and http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html

Comment: @Binayaka Chakraborty I mean create my own true functions

Comment: Here's how the GNU people do it: http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/branches/eglibc-2_17/libc/malloc/malloc.c?view=markup Overview: http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/branches/eglibc-2_17/libc/malloc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution. This code helped me, I got it from IBM Developers.

```
/* Include the sbrk function */ 
#include <unistd.h> 

int has_initialized = 0; 
void *managed_memory_start; 
void *last_valid_address; 

void malloc_init() 
 { 
   /* grab the last valid address from the OS */ 
   last_valid_address = sbrk(0); 

 /* we don't have any memory to manage yet, so 
  *just set the beginning to be last_valid_address 
  */ 
  managed_memory_start = last_valid_address; 

  /* Okay, we're initialized and ready to go */ 
  has_initialized = 1; 
} 

 struct mem_control_block { 
  int is_available; 
  int size; 
 };  

 void free(void *firstbyte) { 
   struct mem_control_block *mcb; 

  /* Backup from the given pointer to find the 
  * mem_control_block 
   */ 
    mcb = firstbyte - sizeof(struct mem_control_block); 
   /* Mark the block as being available */ 
    mcb->is_available = 1; 
   /* That's It! We're done. */ 
   return; 
  } 

 void *malloc(long numbytes) { 
     /* Holds where we are looking in memory */ 
     void *current_location; 

    /* This is the same as current_location, but cast to a 
    * memory_control_block 
    */ 
    struct mem_control_block *current_location_mcb; 

    /* This is the memory location we will return. It will 
    * be set to 0 until we find something suitable 
    */ 
      void *memory_location; 

/* Initialize if we haven't already done so */ 
if(! has_initialized) { 
malloc_init(); 
} 

/* The memory we search for has to include the memory 
* control block, but the user of malloc doesn't need 
* to know this, so we'll just add it in for them. 
*/ 
numbytes = numbytes + sizeof(struct mem_control_block); 

/* Set memory_location to 0 until we find a suitable 
*
 location 
*/ 
memory_location = 0; 

/* Begin searching at the start of managed memory */ 
current_location = managed_memory_start; 

/* Keep going until we have searched all allocated space */ 
while(current_location != last_valid_address) 
{ 
/* current_location and current_location_mcb point 
* to the same address. However, current_location_mcb 
* is of the correct type so we can use it as a struct. 
* current_location is a void pointer so we can use it 
* to calculate addresses. 
*/ 
current_location_mcb = 
(struct mem_control_block *)current_location; 

if(current_location_mcb->is_available) 
{

if(current_location_mcb->size >= numbytes) 
{ 
/* Woohoo! We've found an open, 
* appropriately-size location. 
*/ 

/* It is no longer available */ 
current_location_mcb->is_available = 0; 

/* We own it */ 
memory_location = current_location; 

/* Leave the loop */ 
break; 
} 
} 

/* If we made it here, it's because the Current memory 
* block not suitable, move to the next one 
*/ 
current_location = current_location + 
current_location_mcb->size; 
} 

/* If we still don't have a valid location, we'll 
* have to ask the operating system for more memory 
*/ 
if(! memory_location) 
{ 
/* Move the program break numbytes further */ 
sbrk(numbytes); 

/* The new memory will be where the last valid 
* address left off 
*/ 
memory_location = last_valid_address; 

/* We'll move the last valid address forward 
* numbytes 
*/ 
last_valid_address = last_valid_address + numbytes; 

/* We need to initialize the mem_control_block */ 
current_location_mcb = memory_location; 
current_location_mcb->is_available = 0; 
current_location_mcb->size = numbytes; 
} 

/* Now, no matter what (well, except for error conditions), 
* memory_location has the address of the memory, including 
* the mem_control_block 
*/ 

/* Move the pointer past the mem_control_block */ 
memory_location = memory_location + sizeof(struct mem_control_block); 

/* Return the pointer */ 
return memory_location; 
}
```

Hope it helps...

This may get handy... `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764711/making-your-own-malloc-function-in-c`

Comment: I don't understand how this works :(. How can you treat memory like it was a struct..."current_location_mcb->is_available" how can this work ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is more of a redirection to previous questions

For Malloc
[making your own malloc function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764711/making-your-own-malloc-function-in-c)

For Free
[C - Design your own free( ) function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147081/c-design-your-own-free-function)

And one blog
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/178691-creating-a-custom-malloc-and-free-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

[jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/) is a free, open-source, thread-safe replacement for the libc `malloc()`. Its code is fairly simple, and studying it you will find everything you need to know about creating your own replacement for malloc and other libc functions including:

- How to make the compiler use *your* malloc instead of the native libc's for everything, including the `malloc()` calls in the inner guts of the libc functions;
- How to make it thread-safe;
- How to make it compilable and functional in every platform.

Notice NetBSD and FreeBSD already use jemalloc as default memory allocator.