# Are you allowed to perform pointer arithmetic on an array that you no longer own?

Tags: c

Consider

```
int main()
{
    char* p = malloc(5);
    printf("%td", &p[5] - &p[0]); /*one past the end is allowed*/
    free(p);
    printf("%td", &p[5] - &p[0]); /*I no longer own p*/
}
```

Is the behaviour of this code defined? Are you allowed to perform pointer arithmetic on an array that you no longer own?

Comment: You can do the arithmetic. You may not access the array anymore.

Comment: where did you get that `p[5]` was allowed (one past the end??)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arithmetic on freed pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733814/arithmetic-on-freed-pointer)

Comment: `&p[5]` must not attempt to *dereference* `p`. In order words `&p[5]` must compile to `p + 5` with no dereference on `p`.

Comment: check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147081/c-design-your-own-free-function)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie-- even pointer arithmetic beyond `p+1` is undefined behavior after `p` has been `free`d.

Comment: @FitzwilliamBennet-Darcy: That's true. However, even evaluating the pointer *itself* (say, pointer arithmetic) is undefined behavior when it's out of range of an object (be it a stack- or heap-allocated one). In other words, a pointer, even if not dereferenced, ***must*** point to a location in an object, or the location immediately following one. Thus, your code is undefined behavior. Many (most?) compilers do allow it in practice, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @David Bowling, may I assume, as an example, that a compiler seeing that `p` has been freed, may use the storage location of `p` for some other purpose?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie-- yes, I think so. I think that my earlier comment was wrong, in that even attempting to form the address `p+1` incurs UB, since `p` no longer points to an array object, not even to an array object of 1 element.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're usually allowed to do that on many compilers in many environments.

You have to keep in mind, however, that the ISO C standard doesn't have any requirement for your language when you do it, however: it doesn't define the behavior *any use* of a pointer whose value is "indeterminate".  According to ISO C, the value of `p` after `free(p)` has essentially the same status as if it were uninitialized.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the language lawyer answer, or the practical answer?

The language lawyer answer is, no, it's undefined.

The practical answer is: yes, it'll probably work, but it's a bad idea.  I would always compute the difference (and store it in a variable if necessary) *before* freeing the pointer.

Comment: "*... it's undefined..*" I am with, but seem to be unable to find the related paragraph in the C11-Standard. 6.5.6/8 I feel is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @alk-- what about §6.5.6 9: "When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object...." After `free(p);`, `p` does not point to an array object, I think.